# как подключить библиотеку SFML к игре

Tags: c++, sfml

Я пишу небольшую 2D игру с помощью библиотеки SFML. Но возникла проблема при переносе игры на другой ПК. Программа требует наличие этой самой библиотеки для запуска.Весь интернет перелопатил и не нашел ничего полезного кроме того, что нужно подключить .so файлы к исполняемому,но ни слова о том,как это сделать. Кто-нибудт сталкивался с подобным? Что делать?

Comment: Какая ОС, винда или линукс?

Comment: линукс,но позже планируется и запуск под виндой

Comment: Под виндой это просто, достаточно хранить вместе с экзешником использованные библиотеки в виде `.dll`. На линуксе все сложно, и единого способа похоже нет. Можно попробовать: https://appimage.org/ https://snapcraft.io/